# getting error in MERN TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am using react with node express background.
I am trying to get data from node API in react front end.
Node API is returning data successfully, tested on postman, but when I am trying to get data in react, I am getting error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Here is my API:

```
router.get("/get_data", function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        "users": [
            {
                id: 1,
                username: "samsepi0l"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                username: "D0loresH4ze"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Here is ReactJs code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
    state = {users: []};

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/funi/get_data")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(users => this.setState({users: users.username}));
    }

    render() {
        return (<div className="App">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                {this.state.users.map((user, index) => <div key={index}>{user.username}</div>)}
            </div>);
    }
}

export default App;
```

Screenshot of calling Node API

[image: Screenshot of calling Node API]

Comment: this.setState({ users:users })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this, you have to update state with the array, but you are updating with `string` that's why you are getting error.

Map can be applied to array not to string.

//change (users => this.setState({ users:users})); to (users => this.setState({ //users:users.users}));

```
componentDidMount() {
 fetch('/funi/get_data')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({ users:users.users}));
 }
```

//`return` is missing inside the map.

```
render() {
const { users } = this.state;
return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {users.length > 0 && users.map((user, index) =>
          return  <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
    </div>
);}
```

Comment: I have done changes according to your suggestion, but now it is not printing any username in browser, also not getting any error in console.

Comment: make this change `{this.state.users.map((user, index) => <div key={index}>{user.username}</div>)}.` you are missing `return`

Comment: class App extends Component {
    state = {users: []}
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/funi/get_data')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
    }
    render() {
        const { users } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Users</h1>
                {users.length > 0 && users.map((user, index) =>
                    <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
                )}
            </div>
        );}}

Comment: i mean you have to return `<div>` inside the map loop, i have updated the answer copy render method and check

Comment: it didn't resolve my issue, can you please check it at your end, please check code i have posted you in comment

Comment: could you please console `users ` instead of setting state ? you can try `this.setState({ users:users.users}))`

Comment: thanks, it solve the issue and showing username in browser without any error

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be corrected as follows. You need to assign users which is an array of objects but you are assigning user name which is a string so map isn't working.

And you need to check the length of an array if it's length is greater than zero only then do map on users.

Don't use index as key instead use id from your data as a key

Check below code for better understanding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg'; import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

state = {users: []}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/funi/get_data')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data.users }));
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Users</h1>
            {users.length > 0 && users.map(user =>
                return <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have done changes according to your suggestion, but now it is not printing any username in browser, also not getting any error in console.

Comment: i have tried the code you posted, it is not showing any username

Comment: Can you do console.log of res.data.users in following line .then(res => this.setState({ users: res.data.users })); and share what you get